# How to parse text from an output in Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ping

So i was tasked to a match a batch script that would ping an ip then print if a response was there or not and what I am attempting to do is to first ping, then save it on a text file,then use an if statement so if the string contains the text Request was timed out it would display that the IP is unavailable.

This is my example code

```
@echo off
cls
echo Executing ping....
ping 123.456.789 >> output.txt
pause
echo Here are the results:
findstr "Request" output.txt
if %finstr% == "Request" {
echo IP does exist
}
else {
echo IP does exist
}
```

I was trying to use findstr to get the string but that would involve saving the string and comparing it but I have no idea how to do that. You get the jist of it. Thanks and all help is appreciated very much.

Post scriptum: the if statement is what i think it looks like since i don't ever do batch programming i am a newbie

Comment: It's 2015, use PowerShell ... `if (Test-Connection -Count 1 -ComputerName 8.8.8.8) { echo "Host is up" } else { echo "Host is down" }`

Comment: Newbie or not. Reading the help for the IF command would show you that curly braces are not used.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler do you know that Cobol powers most of the financial transactions in this world.

Comment: @Squashman, and solid rock is the ground which holds up entire cities and skyscrapers, but if you want to build a garden shed over a weekend, nobody would recommend you start with a country sized lump of granite and a chisel. You'd go buy a pre-made shed, some pre-made tools and some pre-made pourable concrete and get on with your life. (That doesn't mean we conclude that COBOL is the best tool for the job, it may well be because COBOL was there first and has inertia, and the risk of change is so high. You don't need to do what the financial industry does unless you need what they need).

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler so we agree that Poweshell is not always the best tool for the job even though it is almost 2016.

Comment: @Squashman Where did I say it was "always the best tool for the job", exactly? I said it was a better idea to use PowerShell (PS) to test-connectivity and switch on the result. It is. I said it's a better tool to be learning for someone who knows neither batch files nor PS. It is. The year matters because Microsoft has been moving the Windows ecosystem hard away from batch and VBscript since ~2009. If it was 2000, batch would be 'the way to script Windows' and a good thing to learn, in 2015 it's 'the legacy way to script Windows', and a bad thing to learn *compared to PS, for everyday uses*.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I never heard of PowerShell, I will take a look at this but this was mostly done as a lesson from a boss. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that there's a far better approach; ERRORLEVEL.

```
 @echo off
 ping -n 1 192.168.1.1 > NUL
 if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   echo Host is down.
 ) else (
   echo Host is up.
 )
```

If ping succeeds, `ERRORLEVEL` will be zero.  If it fails, `ERRORLEVEL` will be 1 (or possibly greater if it fails for other reasons, I suppose...  `if ERRORLEVEL 1` tests for `ERRORLEVEL` >= 1).

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you did a bit?

Comment: That's all well and good, @TessellatingHeckler, but the question was for Batch.

Comment: It seems a bit weird to me, I mostly code in HTML,CSS,and JS. Isn't batch just like PHP?

Comment: Definitely not.  It's much older, inheriting things from DCL and a variety of other older OS command lines scripting languages.

Comment: So SQL is just as old?